# How would I toggle an animation at runtime in React Native using Lottie?

Tags: react-native, lottie

I'm trying to create a save button (basically to bookmark a screen) that toggles animation whether a user taps the button to "save" an item or remove the "save". Tapping the button should call one of the animations whether it's the "on" animation or the "off" animation.

Unfortunately besides iOS I can't find any documentation on toggling an animation on a button in React Native. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here's the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleSaved } from '../../actions';
import Animation from 'lottie-react-native';

import onAnimation from '../animations/heart_On.json';
import offAnimation from '../animations/heart_Off.json';

class SaveButton extends Component {
    isSaved = () => {
        let item = this.props.item;
        if (_.find(this.props.saved, function(i) { return i.type == item.type && i.id == item.id; })) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    toggleSaved = (saved, item) => {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(toggleSaved(saved, item));
        this.animation.play();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={ () => this.toggleSaved(this.props.saved, this.props.item) }
            >
                <Animation
                    ref={ animation => {
                        this.animation = animation;
                    } }
                    style={ styles.icon }
                    loop={ false }
                    source={ this.isSaved() ? onAnimation: offAnimation }
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

SaveButton.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    saved: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    icon: {
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginRight: 10
    }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { saved } = state.saved;

    return {
        saved
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SaveButton);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to have two separate animation elements and then, depending on the state, show or hide (and of course .play()) them accordingly.

So (code in half-pseudo to get the idea):

- state prop like `isSaved`, which defines which animation is currently on stage,
- when saving (or removing) toggle the state to show correct animation and call the `this.refToCorrectAnimation.play()`.

---

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isSaved: false,
  };
}

isSavedVisible() {
  return (this.state.isSaved) ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' };
}

isRemovedVisible() {
  return (!this.state.isSaved) ? { display: 'flex' } : { display: 'none' };
}


toggleSaved(...) {
  if (this.state.isSaved) {
    this.isSavedAnimation.play();
  } else {
    this.isRemovedAnimation.play();
}

render() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleSaved()} ...>
      <Animation style={this.isSavedVisible()} ref={(animation) = this.isSavedAnimation = animation} ... />
      <Animation style={this.isRemovedVisible()} ref={(animation) = this.isRemovedAnimation = animation} ... />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Comment: good one, But I get the zoom animation at the beginning when it loads. So, I position absolute one of the lotie animation and set the conditional opacity on both.